# get array of entries between two specific entries in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am facing a problem of obtaining an array with all entries between 2 dedicated entries.
I have a table, which looks roughly like the following:

```
| Type | State       | Domain | Time     |
|------|-------------|--------|----------|
| A    | eating      | Fruit  | 12:33:11 |
| A    | working     | day    | 12:35:12 |
| A    | working     | day    | 12:44:55 |
| A    | sleep       | day    | 12:59:53 |
| A    | enjoying    | Fruit  | 08:12:04 |
| A    | thinking    | day    | 09:16:32 |
| A    | eating      | Fruit  | 10:44:31 |
| A    | daydreaming | day    | 10:44:33 |
| A    | calling     | day    | 10:59:01 |
| B    | wondering   | Fruit  | 10:00:01 |
| B    | digesting   | day    | 10:49:09 |
| B    | cleaning    | day    | 12:00:27 |
| B    | eating      | Fruit  | 04:03:22 |
```

and I want to get an output as the following:

```
| Type | State       | Domain     | Time     | Intermediate Output             | Array Count | Mode Array                 |
|------|-------------|------------|----------|---------------------------------|-------------|----------------------------|
| A    | eating      | Fruit      | 12:33:11 | ['working', 'working', 'sleep'] | 3           | working                    |
| A    | working     | day        | 12:35:12 | None                            | 0           | None                       |
| A    | working     | day        | 12:44:55 | None                            | 0           | None                       |
| A    | sleep       | day        | 12:59:53 | None                            | 0           | None                       |
| A    | enjoying    | Fruit      | 08:12:04 | ['day']                         | 1           | day                        |
| A    | thinking    | day        | 09:16:32 | None                            | 0           | None                       |
| A    | eating      | Fruit      | 10:44:31 | ['daydreaming', 'calling']      | 2           | ['daydreaming', 'calling'] |
| A    | daydreaming | day        | 10:44:33 | None                            | 0           | None                       |
| A    | calling     | day        | 10:59:01 | None                            | 0           | None                       |
| B    | wondering   | Fruit      | 10:00:01 | ['digesting','cleaning']        | 2           | ['digesting','cleaning']   |
| B    | digesting   | day        | 10:49:09 | None                            | 0           | None                       |
| B    | cleaning    | day        | 12:00:27 | None                            | 0           | None                       |
| B    | eating      | Fruit      | 04:03:22 | []                              | 0           | []                         |
```

Basically doing a partition by *Type* and *Domain* to get the differences in between two distinct domain values. The values in the *Domain* column can only take two values [Fruit, day].
I basically want to obtain all the State names in an array from the first time the domain is Fruit until the next Fruit entry appears. Two other columns should be based on this array *intermediate output* to get the length of the array and the mode of it.
Arbitrary many Fruit entries can appear within one type.
The entire data set is temporally ordered according to the Time column.

Unfortunately, the infrastructure only allows for pyspark, so I can't use pandas.

I would really appreciate any help and tips since I am a pyspark Noob!
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using two window functions to solve this. (Also, assuming that your records will be ordered by the 'Time' column)

Since your 'Domain' can only take two values, I code 'Fruit' as 1 and 'day' as 0. We will do an `incremental sum` on this new domain column to use it as key to group 'State'.

Remove the first element and keep the rest from the output of the `collect_list` function. I'm using the `remove_first_element UDF` to do that.

You don't need the 'array_output' whenever the 'Domain' is 'day'. So replacing it with `None` whenever the 'Domain' is 'day'.

`F.size()` to get the size of the array and a custom UDF `get_multi_mode_list_udf` to get multi mode values

Constructing your dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = StructType([StructField("Type", StringType()), StructField("State", StringType()),\
         StructField("Domain", StringType()), StructField("Time", IntegerType())])

data = [['A', 'eating', 'Fruit', 1], ['A', 'working', 'day', 2], ['A', 'working', 'day', 3], ['A', 'sleep', 'day', 4], ['A', 'enjoying', 'Fruit', 5], ['A', 'thinking', 'day', 6], ['A', 'eating', 'Fruit', 7], ['A', 'daydreaming', 'day', 8], ['A', 'calling', 'day', 9], ['B', 'wondering', 'Fruit', 10], ['B', 'digesting', 'day', 11], ['B', 'cleaning', 'day', 12], ['B', 'eating', 'Fruit', 13]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schema)

df.show()
```

Actual Operation:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("Domain_num", F.when(col("Domain")=="Fruit", 1).otherwise(0))

w1=Window().partitionBy("Type").orderBy("Time")
w2=Window().partitionBy("Type", "incremental_sum")

def remove_first_element(list):
    return list[1:]

remove_first_element_udf = F.udf(remove_first_element, ArrayType(StringType()))

df1 = df1.withColumn("incremental_sum", F.sum("Domain_num").over(w1))\
        .withColumn("array_output", collect_list(col("State")).over(w2))\
        .withColumn("array_output", remove_first_element_udf(col("array_output")))\
        .withColumn("array_output", F.when(col("Domain_num")==0, None).otherwise(col("array_output")))\
        .withColumn("array_count", F.size(col("array_output")))\
        .withColumn("array_count", F.when(col("Domain_num")==0, 0).otherwise(col("array_count")))
```

Finding the mode:

```
from collections import Counter
def get_multi_mode_list(input_array):
    multi_mode = []
    counter_var = Counter(input_array)  
    try:
        temp = counter_var.most_common(1)[0][1]
    except:
        temp = counter_var.most_common(1)
    for i in counter_var: 
        if input_array.count(i) == temp: 
            multi_mode.append(i)
    return(list(set(multi_mode)))

get_multi_mode_list_udf = F.udf(get_multi_mode_list, ArrayType(StringType()))

df1 = df1.withColumn("multi_mode", get_multi_mode_list_udf(col("array_output")))\
        .withColumn("multi_mode", F.when(col("Domain_num")==0, None).otherwise(col("multi_mode")))\
        .drop("Domain_num", "incremental_sum")
```

Output:

```
df1.orderBy("Time").show(truncate=False)

+----+-----------+------+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------------------+
|Type|State      |Domain|Time|array_output             |array_count|multi_mode            |
+----+-----------+------+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------------------+
|A   |eating     |Fruit |1   |[working, working, sleep]|3          |[working]             |
|A   |working    |day   |2   |null                     |0          |null                  |
|A   |working    |day   |3   |null                     |0          |null                  |
|A   |sleep      |day   |4   |null                     |0          |null                  |
|A   |enjoying   |Fruit |5   |[thinking]               |1          |[thinking]            |
|A   |thinking   |day   |6   |null                     |0          |null                  |
|A   |eating     |Fruit |7   |[daydreaming, calling]   |2          |[daydreaming, calling]|
|A   |daydreaming|day   |8   |null                     |0          |null                  |
|A   |calling    |day   |9   |null                     |0          |null                  |
|B   |wondering  |Fruit |10  |[digesting, cleaning]    |2          |[digesting, cleaning] |
|B   |digesting  |day   |11  |null                     |0          |null                  |
|B   |cleaning   |day   |12  |null                     |0          |null                  |
|B   |eating     |Fruit |13  |[]                       |0          |[]                    |
+----+-----------+------+----+-------------------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: This is Amazing! Thank you very, very much! This helped me a lot.

Comment: Happy to help! I've added the code snippet to find out the mode.